# Memory management when generating and downloading a PDF file

Tags: php, codeigniter, memory-management, dompdf

I have 944 rows of data and I have a link to download all those data in PDF format. I am using DOM PDF to generate the PDF file.

The problem is when I click on the download link I get the following error message

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 86 bytes) in ......`

So, to get rid of this error I used the following code before generating the PDF:

`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

But then I get the following error message:

`Server Error
The server for http://www.dorresms.com/student/export_studentcontact took too long to respond. It may be overloaded.`

When I had less data I didn't have any trouble downloading the file.

I am using a shared host and I checked the php ini; I got the following information:

**Resource Limits** : memory_limit (32MB) (Maximum amount of memory a script may consume    256M)

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

### Update

If I limit my query to 280 rows then it generates the PDF, more than 280 rows is creating the problem.

The following is my code to generate PDF. (I am using Codeigniter)

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

include_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

$account_id=$this->authex->get_account_id();

$this->load->model('mod_student');
$data['records'] = $this->mod_student->get_all_student($account_id);            

$html= $this->load->view('student/view_studentcontact_pdf',$data,true); 

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper("a4", "" );

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('Contact_List', array("Attachment" => 0));
```

Comment: Show some code how ur generating the PDF ..may be something is repeating endlessly

Comment: Debug the code by first downloading lesser rows (10-15) & check if you still got the same ? Also post your code it will be helpful .

Comment: I have submitted my code. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @Rikesh As I mention in my question, when I had less rows of data I didn't have trouble downloading the file.thanks

Comment: If your host allows shell access you may try rendering the data offline. If that works then it is definitely a memory issue. Which host are you using? Some allow you to customize your PHP environment to a certain degree, but many limit what you can do through `ini_set()`. You may also have a hard limit on the amount of memory you can use, regardless of what you set in PHP.

Comment: Also, "server took too long to respond" may indicate a script timeout, so you might try setting the [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).